# Ubuntu not showing in boot menu (Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, ubuntu, boot

A couple of years ago, I set up my machine to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu. At that time, it worked as expected and I was able to switch back and forth between Windows and Ubuntu. Today, I tried to swap to Ubuntu and it did not appear in the boot menu, only Windows was there. The drive is still partitioned the way I left it. It has probably been a year since the last time I booted Ubuntu. Could one of the Windows updates have broken it? What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: In the past, I've had Windows Update break booting from grub, but not for a few years,  1. Does the machine boot right to Windows, or show a screen to select OS? 2. Are you using grub to select OS? 3. Have you done a **full** reboot, without Windows Fast Startup or Hibernation? More detail would help get an answer.

Comment: Shutting down with Fast Startup disabled instead of Restarting resolved it, Thanks! Before, I was seeing the *Windows* boot menu.  Now, I'm seeing the manufacturer's boot menu first, followed by the grub menu.

Comment: Glad that helped -- Fast Startup leaves an image of the Windows kernel on the drive, so when booting, it bypasses grub and goes right to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shutting down with Fast Startup disabled instead of Restarting resolved it. Pressing the boot key on the built-in keyboard while Restarting instead of my external keyboard also worked the same. Before, I was seeing only the Windows boot menu: [image]

Now, I'm seeing the manufacturer's boot menu first,[image]

followed by the grub menu.[image]